# open excel sheet pull the value from a cell and store it as a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Basically guys in vb.net I need to open an excel document and read the value of a certain cell(A1 for example) be it text or numerical and store it as a string value to use elsewhere in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
'start Excel app
Dim App1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
App1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' load excel document
exApp.Workbooks.Open(fname)
Dim Sheet1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Sheet1 = exApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
a = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel Interop as in this example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet). Or you can use [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) as in this example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff921204.aspx). For XLSX file you can also develop a custom solution, xlsx are nothing but zipped folder of XML files, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208075/How-to-read-and-write-xlsx-Excel-2007-file-Part-I) might be helpfull.